# ¿Como hacer una gráfica de pie con matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Requiero generar una gràfica de torta (pie) con etiquetas de valores y porcentajes a partir del siguiente dataframe:

```
df_reporte_act = pd.DataFrame({'MES':['JUNIO'],
            'Columna_1':[7133],
            'Columna_2':[5893],
             })
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pandas.plot.pie()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html) es la función que te pinta un gráfico de tarta, pero necesita que el formato de los datos sea diferente.

En principio, necesita que los datos estén en una columna (y no como tú lo tienes en dos) y usará como etiquetas para cada sector de la tarta los valores del `index` (pero tú tienes las etiquetas como nombres de columnas).

En tu ejemplo los datos están así:

```
     MES  Columna_1  Columna_2
0  JUNIO       7133       5893
```

Si cambias el `index` para que sea la columna "MES", lo tendrías así:

```
>>> print(df_reporte_act.set_index("MES"))

       Columna_1  Columna_2
MES                        
JUNIO       7133       5893
```

Y si le haces la "transpuesta" (cambiar filas por columnas) ya te queda como debe ser:

```
>>> print(df_reporte_act.set_index("MES").T)

MES        JUNIO
Columna_1   7133
Columna_2   5893
```

Donde vemos que el dataframe resultante tiene los datos en la columna llamada "JUNIO" y las "etiquetas" de cada dato serían los textos que aparecene en el índice, es decir "Columna_1" y "Columna_2".

En este formato ya es directo obtener el plot:

```
>>> df_reporte_act.set_index("MES").T.plot.pie(y="JUNIO")
```

[image: Resultado]